# Html body inside angular component

Tags: html, css

I am new to angular, so bear me if this is a bit silly.

I am trying to add a  tag inside angular main component which has background image. But that image does not span the whole page. It leaves out some space above, i.e between browser address bar and image.

This is my app.component.html

```
<body class="landing-bg-image" style="padding-bottom: 300px;">
</body>
```

and this is my corresponding css.

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.landing-bg-image {
    background-size: auto 100vh;
    background: #0a1215 url(../images/back-image.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-origin: content-box;
}
```

Stackblitz url:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwqobu

Screenshot:
[Screenshot of the space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTEYq.jpg)

Comment: Probably because `<body>` had a default margin of 8px.

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible.... plunker, jsfiddle? This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: Hi @JunKang, applied margin: 0px !important; but still no luck.

Comment: I looked at your stackblitz. Don't put `margin: 0` in the app component css. Put it in  your style.css file as follows: `body {margin: 0;}` You're putting a `<body>` tag inside your app component, which is the one your altering with the css in app.component.css. You should probably change your `<body>` tag in your app component to div instead.

Comment: Thanks @JunKang, That was my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JunKang,

Moving `body` to index.html file(with margin zero) and adding  component(having div with background) inside body solved the problem.

Stackblitz url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwqobu

Answer (score 0):

Try to inspect **body** html element with bowser inspect element tool. And try to find padding style property for body. And update padding property as mentioned below:

> padding : 0px important! ;